# is there anyway to to fetch reviews at google play developer console programmatically?

Tags: android, google-play

We can track "RATINGS & REVIEWS" at Google Play Developer Console for our android apps(as an admin). I wonder if it is possible to get these "RATINGS & REVIEWS" programmatically(i.e. getting as json or rss)?
Or should I try to write a code block which parses that page?

**Edit:** I've written and I'm currently using my parser. But I think Google should give use an official solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now it is available. Thanks Google.

> Ratings and reviews are also available for programmatic access through
>   [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage) and the [gsutil tool](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil). Your data, updated daily, is
>   stored in this private bucket:

**Edit 05.30.2016:** At io16 [Google Play Review Api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews) is announced. Also official app for android; [Google Play Developer Console App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.playconsole)

Comment: I found the same thing the other day. I can pull the CSVs no problem and place them on my Google Drive. Now...are there any examples of how to process these CSVs and summarize them in other useful ways? For example, average rating ... per device model ... per version code?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the console has an RSS feed.

There's a handy Chrome extension(by Google, in fact) here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-subscription-extensio/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd which you can use to pull RSS feeds out of pages that might not necessarily tell you they are there. Appreciate this doesn't help for this question but it might come in handy in future :)

Comment: +1 for your answer but I couldn't use it for google play developer console.

Answer (score 1):

You check this project. It downloads all reviews using gsutil and then sends you an email and/or a Slack message.
https://github.com/rboundi/interstellar

It's very simple to setup and you can run it as a cronjob.